# Python urlencode don't encode special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, urlencode

I'm forming a post request.

```
mydict = {'key1': 'value@1', 'key2': 'value@2'}
encoded_dict = urllib.urlencode(mydict)
```

This will result into

```
key1=value%401&key2=value%402
```

What I really want is

```
key1=value@1&key2=value@2
```

Any other way to this?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to, `%40` is url encoded `@`, if you dont want it encoded then don't use `urllib.urlencode()`.

Comment: I want to send the request in post format like key=value type. I can write the code for it but I was wandering why it needs to encode post data.   The server onto which I'm sending data doesn't accept encoded format data.

Comment: It's not for encoding your post data. `urlencode` is just for encoding urls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do your own thing, you'll have to write your own encoder. eg:

```
mydict = {'key1': 'value@1', 'key2': 'value@2'}
>>> "&".join("{}={}".format(*i) for i in mydict.items())
'key2=value@2&key1=value@1'
```

But why not just use JSON?

Comment: Well, *if* OP wanted to use this encoding for URL encoding data for a `GET` query string, he could just use `urllib.quote_plus(mydict, safe='@')`. But as you said in the comments, that doesn't make any sense for `POST` requests.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but serves the purpose. Thank you John for the answer :)

Comment: I needed to do this unescaping of @ too to handle some URL templating employed by Bokeh for their [openurl](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#openurl) column connection to a column data source which uses `@` as a metacharacter to substitute columns with. It would be nice if  urllib supported a syntax to escape the conversion of special html characters. I think for now I'll use the urllib encoding and follow it by a `.replace('%40' , '@' )`

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting [Lukas Graf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599111/lukas-graf) comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31469226/1368849) as I think this needs more prominence.

I hit a problem where I was trying to encode a string to match that expected by an API call. That API call needed a json payload, which had an encoded data value (complicated - and not my API, so not in my gift to change!)

Anyway, the encoded json value didn't require `=` or `&` encoding. To skip the encoding of these characters, I used this:

```
import urllib.parse

# more code here

parsed = urllib.parse.quote_plus(unencoded_string, safe='=&')

# more code here, too
```

And to answer the question, change your original code...

```
mydict = {'key1': 'value@1', 'key2': 'value@2'}
encoded_dict = urllib.urlencode(mydict)
```

... to ...

```
mydict = {'key1': 'value@1', 'key2': 'value@2'}
encoded_dict = urllib.parse.quote_plus(mydict, safe='@')
```